# Saving Many-Many In The Assignments Table Yii

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, relational-database, yii-extensions

I know that this is a battered topic but, I am a complete newbie and I have been trying to get my head around this problem for quite a while now but haven't been able to get it.

I have two tables : Post and Tags

Now the relationship defined in this scenario is a many-many. And hence it has a table named 'tbl_tags_has_tbl_post'.
This is storing the assignment between the relations.

Now I am taking the data for the the "tag" model in my "post" model and I have been able to save the data for the tags from the Post form. Now however, I have not been able to assign the values in the 'tbl_tags_has_tbl_post' table.

I have tried even using CAdvancedArRelationship extension and plugin but still to no avail.

This is my DB structure graphically :

[image]

This is the relationship that I have defined in my Post table :

```
public function relations()
        {
                // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
                // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
                return array(
                        'comments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'tbl_post_id'),
                        'author' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'tbl_user_id'),
                        'tagsRelation' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tags', 'tbl_tags_has_tbl_post(tbl_post_id, tbl_tags_id)'),
                        'commentCount' => array(self::STAT,'Comment','tbl_post_id'), // this shall count the number of comments present
                );
        }
```

And this is the relationship that I have defined in my Tags model:

```
public function relations()
        {
                // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
                // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
                return array(
                        'posts' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Post', 'tbl_tags_has_tbl_post(tbl_tags_id, tbl_post_id)'),
                );
        }
```

And this is my actionCreate() method in my PostController class :

```
public function actionCreate()
        {
                $model=new Post;

                $tags = new Tags; // This is for initializing the second model


                $model->tbl_user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;

                // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
                // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

                if(isset($_POST['Post'],$_POST['Tags']))
                {
                        $model->attributes=$_POST['Post'];
                        $tags->attributes = $_POST['Tags'];
                        $valid=$model->validate();
                $valid=$tags->validate() && $valid;

                if($valid)
        {
            // use false parameter to disable validation

            $tags->save(false);
            // ...redirect to another page
            // 

        }
                        if($model->save()){

                        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                        }
                }

                $this->render('create',array(
                        'model'=>$model,
                        'tags' =>$tags,
                ));
        }
```

So now, what I want to be able to do is, whenever a Post is created with few tags, the assignment table should automatically be filled as well, for ex :

tbl_post_id tbl_tags_id
  1              1
  2              1
  2              2

Something like that.

I have even tried to use the CAdvancedAr Extension as well, but I have not been able to get it to run. I am really clueless, I have tried a lot of stuffs but have not been able to insert values into the assignments table.

If I was to use the extension can anyone please describe the method to do so in this scenario?

Can anybody please guide me as to where am I going wrong and what would I need to do?
I am sorry if this question is a really old one. But I am really stuck here.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I'll show how i'm doing this. Maybe its not the best way but still it works.
I use `afterSave` function. In your case you'll want to use it in post model.

```
protected function afterSave()
    {
        parent::afterSave();
        $relation_table=new TablehasPosts;//your relation model here
        $relation_table->tbl_post_id=$this->id;//post id here to relation model
        $output=array();
        foreach($_POST[tag_id] as $tag_id)//depends on what you have to define tags //id's in your form (checkboxlist, multiselect etc...) 
        {
          array_push($output,$tag_id);//push your id's to some array
        }
        $relation_table->tbl_tags_id=serialize($output);//in your way to store this         
     }
```

This is an example how i handle it. I tried to write close to your models.
Hope this will help you atleast to see the line.